# ERROR: XX000: ValueError: Expected a datetime object. Please look at svl_udf_log for more information

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I'm created python UDF in redshift for checking whether my data has valid date entries (if not return NULL).

UDF successfully created but when I am passing value to function its throwing error.

Python code is running fine in Google colab. But not in redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_isdate(date_text character varying)
  RETURNS timestamp  without time zone
stable
as $$
import datetime
def validate(dt):
    try:
        ti = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,'%m/%d/%Y')
        return ti.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    except TypeError:
        return None
    except ValueError:
        try:
            ti = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
            return ti.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        except ValueError:
            return None   
return validate(date_text)
$$ language plpythonu;
```

I expect `12/22/2003` for this  - `SELECT public.fn_isdate('2003-12-22');`
and
`NULL` for this - `SELECT public.fn_isdate('03-12-22');`

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You declare your function as returning `timestamp without time zone` and then you return a python `string`. 
Not converting date to string does the trick:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sbochniak.fn_isdate(date_text character varying)
  RETURNS timestamp  without time zone
  stable
as $$
import datetime
def validate(dt):
    try:
        ti = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,'%m/%d/%Y')
        return ti
    except TypeError:
        return None
    except ValueError:
        try:
            ti = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
            return ti
        except ValueError:
            return None
return validate(date_text)
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Then:

```
SELECT
   sbochniak.fn_isdate('2003-12-22') as a,
   sbochniak.fn_isdate('03-12-22') as b;
```

returns:

```
a                           b
2003-12-22 00:00:00.000000  <NULL>
```